# React Router render blank page when multiple slashed path and showing Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-dom, unexpected-token

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";
import "./scss/common.scss";
import Home from "./views/Home";
import Login from "./views/Login/index";
import SignUp from "./views/SignUp/index";
import TwitterSingupCallback from "./views/SNS/TwitterSignupCallback/index";
import TwitterLoginCallback from "./views/SNS/TwitterLoginCallback/index";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route exact path="/sign-up" component={SignUp} />
        <Route exact path="/callback/twitter/signup" component={TwitterSingupCallback} />
        <Route exact path="/callback/twitter/login" component={TwitterLoginCallback} />
        <Redirect to="/" />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import "./authLayout.scss";
import Bg from "./bg";
import CompanyNameLogo from "../../common/CompanyNameLogo/index";
import { ToastContainer } from 'react-toastify';
import "./TwitterLoginCallback.scss";
import AuthLayout from "../../../components/layouts/auth/index";
import { CONSTANTS } from "../../../constants";
import { getQueryStringByName } from "../../../helper";
import { authActions } from "../../../redux/actions/auth";
const authType = CONSTANTS.auth.type;

class TwitterLoginCallback extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    let url = window.location.href;
    let oauth_token = getQueryStringByName('oauth_token', url);
    let oauth_verifier = getQueryStringByName('oauth_verifier', url);
    if (oauth_token && oauth_verifier) {
      let params = {
        "type": authType.TWITTER,
        "snsAccessToken": oauth_token,
        "twitterTokenSecret": oauth_verifier
      }
      this.props.loginRequest(params);
    } else {
      window.location.href = CONSTANTS.pageUrls.LOGIN;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <div className="auth-layout">
        <ToastContainer />
        <Bg />
        <CompanyNameLogo />
        <div className={"wrap-page-container " + (this.props.className || "")}>
          <div className="page-container">
            <div className="inner-div" />
          </div>
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {

  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    loginRequest: params => dispatch(authActions.loginRequest(params))
  };
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TwitterLoginCallback);
```

[image]

[image]

localhost:3000/login and mydomain.com/login in s3 are working fine.

localhost:3000/callback/twitter/login this also working good where

in s3 mydomain.com/callback/twitter/login is showing white blank page and showing "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'" error in console.

I tried some solutions from others queries but problem not solved. Please help.

Comment: this error usually means you are not parsing JSON correctly in the request/response. in your request, if you are sending a body in the request you should be using `JSON.stringify({})`  on the body and on the response you should be using `res.json()` in your .`then()` => also make sure to set your request headers

Comment: Include your TwitterLoginCallback component in the question!

Comment: Json format was ok. I have updated with new files and images. See the images in sources, they are not in same structure

Answer (score 0):

Few things you have to improve:

1. Return state in mapStateToProps

`function mapStateToProps(state) {   return state; }`

2. Wrap it around some div or React.Fragment in your second screenshot.

`{this.props.children}` becomes `<div>{this.props.children}</div>`

Comment: That's helpful. In first screenshot static folder is inside callback/twitter but it's not supposed to go there like in second screenshot

Comment: Yes. that's the reason why it was unable to find your JSX code, and thus gave a blank page.

Comment: It didn't solve the problem, I tested after deployment. Actually, in two screenshots the source directory structures are different, may be need to fix the base but I cant.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63351349/css-was-not-loaded-because-its-mime-type-text-html-is-not-text-css-and-s

could you please check this?